# GORM inheritance and GSP

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

Hi I'm doing an application with Grails.
It is an application to manage the invoices.
Each invoice has a list of products.
Each product can be one of 3 types with different properties.
So, I've done the model with

```
class Invoice{
     static hasMany = [products: Product]
}

abstract class Product{
    static belongsTo = [invoice: Invoice]
    abstract int getPrice()
}

class ProductA extends Product{
     //implementation of getPrice using its own properties
}
```

now I have no idea on how to manage it in the GSP point of view.

I know that Grails manage the inheritance using a *class* column, so, when I'm writing a form to add the product should I have to manage also this class input?

something like this:

```
 <g:textField name="products[0].class" value="ProductA" />
```

I'm pretty new with Grails, I know Spring and also with it I don't have idea on how manage it, every suggestion is good.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Product need not belong to an Invoice. A one way hasMany relationship from Invoice to Product is enough. And you need not have the base class, extending class model for your Product class at all. You can add a

```
String productType
```

to your Product class and maybe add a inList constraint:

```
static constraints = {
    productType(inList: ['A','B','C'])
}
```

You can have a g.select to define your product type and when your form submits with a product name, and type you need to bind it or create a new domain object and save it.

```
new Product(params).save()
```

Comment: the problem is that for a different productType I have different fields and a different way to calculate the price...Do I have to create one big class with all those fields?

Comment: Ok then instead of the String productType in your Product class, you can have ProductType productType. This way you have a class called ProductType in which you can have a List<Field> fields or just List<String> fields